# What sites use jqMobi?

Tags: jqmobi

I am looking at using [jqMobi](http://www.jqmobi.com/) to write a mobile version of a website for a client. I really want to see more examples of it in use, as just [the Kitchen Sink demo](http://jqmobi.com/testdrive/) isn't enough. I want to see *actual* sites that run it. What sites exist that use jqMobi?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?  We see a lot of apps coming through appMobi being built using jqMobi.  Badoo used the 1.1 branch for their app.

Comment: @Ian I'm just looking for any examples, preferably actual websites, as that's what I'm looking to build with jqMobi.

Comment: I don't have a list of sites I can give out.  If you want to ping me with any question (my first name @appmobi.com) I'll be happy to answer any questions you want.  I can give you a list of some apps in the appstore using it.

Answer (score 0):

Badoo uses [jqMobi](http://www.jqmobi.com/). Visit with an iPhone or Android device.